# How to resample and concatenate properly the wav files using sox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, concatenation, sox

Code is running but it gives multiline output, while I need in a single horizontal  line

Current output format-

sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_103
.wav -r 12000 -t raw/home/randy/mechanical/raw/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_103
.raw

sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_104
.wav -r 12000 -t raw/home/randy/mechanical/raw/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_104
.raw

.....

sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttsmf_007/ttomf_007_189
.wav -r 12000 -t raw/home/randy/mechanical/raw/ttsmf_007/ttomf_007_189
.raw

Desired output format-

sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_103.wav..........ttsmf_007_103.raw

sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_104.wav..........ttsmf_007_104.raw

................................................................................

sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttomf_007/ttomf_007_189.wav..........ttomf_007_189.raw

----------------------------CODE-----------------------------------------------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

fo= open("ml.ctl","r")
for line in fo.readlines():
    a1 = line[0:]
    y = "sox"+ " " + "/home/randy/mechanical/wav/"+ str(a1)+".wav"+ " " + "-r"+ " " + "12000"+ " " + "-t" + " " + "raw" +"/home/randy/mechanical/raw + str(a1) + ".raw"
    print(y)
fo.close()
fo= open("newmlt.ctl","w")
fo.close()
```

Comment: `y = re.sub("\n", ' ', y)` replace the carriage return to space, first `import re`

Comment: Which line, can you elaborate.

Comment: between `y =... ` and `print(y)`

Comment: Code is running, but it gives one more white space after the tag values                       sox.............ttsmf_007_103(oneextrawhitespace) .wav..........ttsmf_007_103(oneextrawhitespace) .raw                                                                                                      sox home/randy/mechanical/wav/ttsmf_007/ttsmf_007_103 .wav..........ttsmf_007_103.raw

Comment: after what? at the end of sentence? I don't think is relevant to do the job

Comment: means between line[-1:-3] there is no space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136756/discussion-between-andy-and-zital).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the carriage return with regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

fo= open("ml.ctl","r")
for line in fo.readlines():
    a1 = line[0:]
    y = "sox"+ " " + "/home/randy/mechanical/wav/"+ str(a1)+".wav"+ " " + "-r"+ " " + "12000"+ " " + "-t" + " " + "raw" +"/home/randy/mechanical/raw + str(a1) + ".raw"
    y = re.sub("\n", '', y)
    print(y)
fo.close()
fo= open("newmlt.ctl","w")
fo.close()
```

anyway I think that the problem is in the original file ml.ctl or the way to read it